# AWS: Windows instances cannot see each other with Akka

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, akka

I have a cluster of 3 EC2 instances:

- one linux node that we will name L1 in a security group S1 on which the Akka leader is running
- 2 windows nodes W1 and W2 in a security group S2

The security groups both accept all inbound traffic from S1 and S2.
If I start only L1 and W1 and run on them Akka processes to be part of the same cluster, then everything works fine: communication is established in both directions. The akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname I use is $HOSTNAME on Linux and %computername% on Windows.

However, as soon as I start W2 and the akka process in there, both W1 and W2 are rejected by the leader. If I look at the logs on W1 and W2, I notice that the 2 windows machines are unable to talk to each other, what is really weird. Is the computername something that does not work between 2 instances ? I really have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue after all:

- I had to the change the "set computer name" settings in the EC2ConfigService settings on the box
- I had to disable the Windows firewall